# Can NetBeans 8.0 automatically change autogenerated Swing code?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, mouselistener, jradiobutton

I have two RadioButtons and this is the code that keeps getting set for them:

```
jRadioButton6.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            jRadioButton6MouseClicked(evt);
        }
    }
```

I modified in an text editor the method to this:

```
   jRadioButton6.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            jRadioButton6MouseClicked();

        }
    }
```

It appears making modifications to the interface triggers this behavior.

Comment: Did you use Netbeans to change it or a different text editor? Did you refresh everything in Netbeans so it knowns the file has changed, or restarted the thing / recompiled your code?

Comment: I have a backup version of my code which contains the modifications and I use Beyond Compare to return to a workable version or in this case to restore the methods. The backup version is in a different folder and I saved the changes restarted NedBeans, sometimes it works to run the code, I haven't been able figure out what causes this.

Comment: It appears modifying the interface triggers the edit.

Comment: Do not add a `MouseListener`, but - using java 8: `jRadioButton6.addItemListener(e -> jRadioButtonMouseClicked());`. That maybe does not need templating.

Comment: @Alexandru Cimpanu use ActionListener or ItemListener for JRadioButton, without recrusive whatever to MouseListener

Comment: Another way that I found is to play with the design of the components until you are satisfied with the appearance and then modify the code with other editors. And always have a backup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to modify the auto-generated code. There is even a warning at the start of the code:

```
    /**
    * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
    * regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
```

So in the *Design* view I should have selected the *jRadioButton* and under the *Events* I should have selected *itemStateChanged* and set the function that I wanted to be called for that event.

I did a compare of my mistake in the left and the solution on the right:
[image: Compare]